# How to export named imports from an ES2015 module with Flow

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

The following gives me `unexpected identifier` errors

```
/* @flow */

import A from './A'

const B = A
export default A
export B
```

CommonJS modules work:

```
module.exports = { A, B }
```

I would prefer to use the form `export A from './A'` (which is still in proposal).

How can I do these things without Flow complaining?

I'm basically creating an index.js file in a folder with components to bundle them for easy imports elsewhere. Using Flow you will get an error  trying to import a component which is not available in the exports, which is essential to me since it's so easy to forget to add a new component during development.

Comment: Why are you exporting it two times?

Comment: That's just a test for using default export and a named export together. Normally I would write `export A from './A'` but that doesn't work either

Comment: Are you looking for `export { A as default, A as B };`?

Comment: Hey that works for Flow at least! I still have to import and export separately, so `export A from './A'` would be more convenient, but I can live with this. Thanks!

Comment: `export A from './A';` is short for `export { default as A } from './A';` so you can always use that.

Comment: Oh nice! Thanks 